# Expected a dimension of size 5 but got array with shape (10000, 64, 173, 1) (CNN + LSTM on GTZAN dataset)

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, neural-network, lstm, faster-rcnn

I am trying to implement a CNN + LSTM architecture on [GTZAN](http://marsyas.info/downloads/datasets.html) dataset. 
I will explain my training and validation sets below:

```
X_train.shape #(10000, 64, 173, 1)
Y_train.shape #(10000, 10, 1)
X_valid.shape #(2000, 64, 173, 1)
Y_valid.shape #(2000, 10)
```

My model is like below:

```
input_shape = (10000, 64, 173, 1)

model = Sequential()
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(24, 5, 5, activation='relu', subsample=(5, 4),
                                 border_mode='valid'), input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))
model.add(LSTM(64, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dense(output_dim=1, activation = "softmax"))
model.summary()
```

Model compile:

```
from keras.optimizers import Adam
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr = 1e-5), loss="categorical_crossentropy", metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Model Fit:

```
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=20, verbose=2)
history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=90, batch_size=32, validation_data= (X_valid, Y_valid), callbacks=[early_stopping])
```

But I get an error saying,

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected
>   time_distributed_126_input to have 5 dimensions, but got an array with
>   shape (10000, 64, 173, 1)

what am I doing wrong? I am new to this

Answer (score 0):

Hello Professor Liu Yong. My name is Fu Chao. I am a graduate student at Huazhong University of Science and Technology. My research direction is the classification of audio signals. I am very interested in the public data set 'GTZAN' that you use. However, I ca n’t download it on the Internet anymore, and scientific research has fallen into a bottleneck.
So I would like to ask you, can you send me the data set?Thank you very much

Comment: Hello fuchsia, I dont know which professor you are talking about. You can find the GTZAN dataset on my github [here](https://github.com/EsratMaria/MusicGenreRecogniton) in the genres folder.